# Chromedriver won't run as root despite --no-sandbox option

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I can't get Chromedriver to run in a Docker, and it seems I'm passing everything as needed, but it still throws the 'root with sandbox' error and quits.

```
2019-02-15 15:30:22 INFO : Using chromedriver set in webdriver.chrome.driver: /usr/bin/google-chrome
2019-02-15 15:30:22 INFO : Setting ChromeDriver options {browserName=chrome, goog:chromeOptions={args=[--start-maximized, headless, --no-sandbox], extensions=[], prefs={profile.default_content_settings.popups=0, download.prompt_for_download=false, download.default_directory=/home/jenkins/workspace/..../}}}
[1036:1036:0215/153022.769651:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(89)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.
Feb 15, 2019 3:30:42 PM org.openqa.selenium.os.OsProcess checkForError
SEVERE: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
Failure in before hook:Hooks.getDriver(Scenario)
```

I've logged the ChromeOptions content and it's clear `args` contains `--no-sandbox` - What could be the problem here?

---

- Google Chrome 70.0.3538.77
- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:jar: 3.141.59

---

*Similar to [How to run selenium chromedriver as root? (not working even with --no-sandbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48828470/how-to-run-selenium-chromedriver-as-root-not-working-even-with-no-sandbox) but that was solved by a Python dependency - this is a Java project.*

---

I've also added `-Dwebdriver.chrome.args="--no-sandbox"` to the Maven command.

Comment: Which version of ChromeDriver are you using? It should be ChromeDriver 2.45 for Chrome v70

Comment: I'll see if I can find out, but I thought the 2.xx was a Python thing? It's Chrome 70 installed, isn't that the only dependency outside Java? If that's the case, I'm pointing the chromedriver at chrome itself which is probably wrong.

Comment: Turns out I'm using Chromedriver 2.43. I'll try updating to 2.45.

Comment: Thank you @JensDibbern - this was the root of the problem, and forcing the right version fixes this. Could you post an answer and I'll accept it? If you have a link to a page listingwhich Chrome needs which ChromeDriver add that too, it'd be super-useful to have that info.

Comment: under what circumstance would you want to run as root?

Comment: Good question - It runs as root in the docker container that's used as a Jenkins slave. It's not uncommon to do this despite the potential security concerns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use matching Chrome and ChromeDriver versions for Selenium to work properly. There is a list at http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads.

At the time of this post:

- If you are using Chrome version 73, please download ChromeDriver
  73.0.3683.20
- If you are using Chrome version 72, please download ChromeDriver 2.46 or ChromeDriver 72.0.3626.69
- If you are using Chrome version 71, please download ChromeDriver 2.46 or ChromeDriver 71.0.3578.137

Comment: Thanks! It looks like the version numbers aligned for v73 then? I hope so, this will make it much easier.